# Is it idiomatic to use an infinitive after a gerund?

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds, infinitives, idiomatic-language

Is it idiomatic to use an infinitive after a gerund? For example:

> 1. Stop trying to impress others.
> 2. Stop trying to please everyone.

Can we use an infinitive after gerund?

Is it grammatically normal?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. If you use 'google books' for search ( with 'stop-trying-to' as a key phrase), you'll even find many results in book *titles*.